# How to make ConEmu treat `~` as `%USERPROFILE%` (user home)?

Tags: windows, command-line, conemu

I'd like use `~` as user home,  `%USERPROFILE%` is too long.

But I don't know where to set this alias/mapping, since windows cmd not support alias, I am afraid ConEmu can not do this.

Answer (score 0):

False. `cmd.exe` support aliases. Moreover, ConEmu [provides easy way](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsEnvironment.html) to setup them.

So you may define in ConEmu Environment:

```
alias ~=cd /d "%USERPROFILE%"
```

And after that you may execute in cmd.exe prompt:

```
D:\Sources> ~
C:\Users\Max>
```

Or you may create an alias for `cd~` to make it more natural:

```
alias cd~=cd /d "%USERPROFILE%"
```

And execute it

```
D:\Sources> cd~
C:\Users\Max>
```

Comment: This looks like it answers the OP's question about an alias, but does not indicate typical ~ = home usage.  Is there a way to make "echo ~" provide the same output as "echo %USERPROFILE%"?

Comment: You may define alias for `echo~`.

Comment: That still doesn't treat ~ like %USERPROFILE%. I know this answer seems to directly address the OP's comment about aliases, but I don't see this answer as really answering the core question.  For instance, I can say: "copy filename %USERPROFILE%\Downloads".  I don't see how your approach could let me say "copy filename ~\Downloads".  The "echo ~" was just one simple example that is an easy way to suitably test this flexibility, and your idea there doesn't provide that sought-after flexibility at all.  I don't seek to discourage: If there's an available solution, it'd be nice to know